# Showing the uploaded csv file on Django template

Tags: django, csv, django-templates

I have a project that accepts an uploaded .csv file and shows it on the admin via the models.py. What I want to happen is to show these uploaded .csv file on the template.

my views are:

```
def data_upload(request):
    template = "home.html"

    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render(request, template)

    csv_file = request.FILES['file']
    if not csv_file.name.endswith('.csv'):
        messages.error(request, 'Please upload a .csv file.')

    data_set = csv_file.read().decode('ISO-8859-1')
    io_string = io.StringIO(data_set)
    next(io_string)
    for column in csv.reader(io_string, delimiter=','):
        _, created = Table.objects.update_or_create(
            page=column[0], 
            keyword=column[1], 
            interval=column[2], 
            email=column[3], 
            notes=column[4], 
            billing=column[5],
        )
    context = {
    'tables': Table.objects.all()
    }
    return render(request, template, context)
```

The views are already working when I upload the .csv file.

On the home.html file, this is what I did:

```
                       <table class="table table-condensed">
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>...</th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <th class="center-align" scope="row"><i class="small material-icons green">check</i></th>
                            {% for t in tables %}
                            <td class="center-align">{{t.page}}</td>
                            <td class="center-align">{{t.keyword}}</td>
                            <td class="center-align">{{t.interval}}</td>
                            <td class="center-align">{{t.email}}</td>
                            <td class="center-align">{{t.notes}} </td>
                            <td class="center-align">{{t.billing}}</td>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </tr>
                       </table>
```

How do I properly iterate on the template to show what I uploaded on my html file?

Comment: Why are you doing CSV by column? By row would make it easier in template.

Comment: @MatthewGaiser I don't get it. How would you do it?

Comment: The CSV isn't actually being done by column.  It's being done by row.  The guy in the mastercode.online tutorial video (https://youtu.be/BppyfPye8eo) uses `column` as the loop variable in the `for` loop, but we all know that `csv.reader()` returns rows or lines, not columns.  He should have named the loop variable `row` or `line` to make more sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**If you don't upload a file, the code doesn't go past the first return**

Unless a CSV is uploaded, the code stops here and thus no data is sent to the template. That is why {{ tables }} returned blank. While the data is in the database, the {{tables}} in the template is never populated in this render.

```
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render(request, template)
```

Only if a CSV is actually uploaded does this output anything and fill out the table. Any request which is not from the big green upload button does not run code which would give the {{tables}} in the template any data.

The code below only runs if the CSV is uploaded that time.

```
csv_file = request.FILES['file']
    if not csv_file.name.endswith('.csv'):
        messages.error(request, 'Please upload a .csv file.')

    data_set = csv_file.read().decode('ISO-8859-1')
    io_string = io.StringIO(data_set)
    next(io_string)
    for column in csv.reader(io_string, delimiter=','):
        _, created = Table.objects.update_or_create(
            page=column[1], 
            keyword=column[2], 
            interval=column[3], 
            email=column[4], 
            notes=column[5], 
            billing=column[6],
        )
    context = {
        'tables': Table.objects.all()
    }
    print(Table.objects.all())
    return render(request, template, context)
```

Does this work?

```
context = {'tables': Table.objects.all()}
```

This assumes that the only elements in Table are elements from the CSV.

**Edit, how to fix the template**

Change this

```
                            <tr>
                                <th class="center-align" scope="row"><i class="small material-icons green">check</i></th>
                                {% for t in tables %}
                                <td class="center-align">{{t.page}}</td>
                                <td class="center-align">{{t.keyword}}</td>
                                <td class="center-align">{{t.interval}}</td>
                                <td class="center-align">{{t.email}}</td>
                                <td class="center-align">{{t.notes}} </td>
                                <td class="center-align">{{t.billing}}</td>
                                {% endfor %}
                            </tr>
```

```
{% for t in tables %}
                            <tr>
                                <th class="center-align" scope="row"><i class="small material-icons green">check</i></th>

                                <td class="center-align">{{t.page}}</td>
                                <td class="center-align">{{t.keyword}}</td>
                                <td class="center-align">{{t.interval}}</td>
                                <td class="center-align">{{t.email}}</td>
                                <td class="center-align">{{t.notes}} </td>
                                <td class="center-align">{{t.billing}}</td>

                            </tr>
                            {% endfor %}
```

to this in `home.html`

Basically, make the `<tr></tr>` tags go inside the for loop and not outside.

Comment: Correct, the elements on the Talbe are from the .csv. But it still doesn't show.

Comment: What happens if you print(Table.objects.all())?

Comment: Interesting.. It only shows ```<QuerySet [<Table: https://www.calltuke.com/>, <Table: https://www.advancedhomeinspection.pro/>, <Table: https://www.donutdash.com/>, <Table: https://www.jay-bunyan.com/>, <Table: https://www.lacazuelafairfield.com/>]>```

Comment: Is that what is supposed to be in there?

Comment: Can you send me a pic of what {{ tables }} looks like just dumped on the template page?

Comment: These are only one row of the csv file.

Comment: Nothing. What do you think is the problem with this?

Comment: Check your database to ensure the data is in there?

Comment: It is. Once I upload a csv file, it shows on the Admin.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199411/discussion-between-matthew-gaiser-and-highcenburg).

Comment: I ran makemigrations && migrate again to make sure I migrated but there are no migrations to apply tho.

Comment: drop your github username if you want to see the repository

Comment: @MattGaiser is my github.

Comment: Added you as a collaborator

Comment: Figured it out. Let me write it up.

Comment: You will want to kick yourself for what we missed.

Comment: what did we miss? hahaha

Comment: See the new answer. We were literally debugging code which was not running.

Comment: this still not loads any data sorry

Comment: what did you put in the template?

Comment: I didn't need to change anything in the template.

Comment: Did you add anything via the admin? I think I mentioned that the uploaded csv should be parsed onto the template. I didn't change a thing on the loop on the template but it still really doesn't show.

Comment: @Highcenburg Sorry, I missed this earlier. Although seriously, I did not change anything of significance. https://imgur.com/a/JklWuGL. Here are screenshots of every change I made.

Comment: And here is a video of the app working. 

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pWyTdwK7_AM&feature=youtu.be

Comment: Oh yeah it worked already on my end too. But the problem is the data only loops through the row, not the column. How do we go about that?

Comment: Yes. Is that possible?

Comment: That was fast. Yes, like that. How'd I do it?

Comment: I've tried for column, row in csv.reader on the views and looped through each of the column but it did not show any data.

Comment: You are a big help to this issue. I'm on to the background tasks. Thank you!

Comment: No problem. Good luck with the project.